# How does memcpy works with void pointers?

Tags: c, memcpy

I am trying to memcpy from one ptr to another. I know the size that I want to copy. Both the destination and source pointers are void pointers. Is this valid? Does it actually copy the ELEMENT_SIZE (integer like 128) from source to the destination? I know this is not the most ideal thing to do. But I want to know if this works.

```
memcpy(to_add, element_ptr, ELEMENT_SIZE);
```

Comment: Yes it works. It behaves the same as looping character pointers over that number of bytes.

Comment: Why would you think it would not work considering that `memcpy` is defined to accept void pointers?

Comment: Give it a try. If it doesn't work the you expect it to work, come back to SO with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it actually copy the ELEMENT_SIZE (integer like 128) from source
>   to the destination?

Yes, If you know the size information,then its working fine.

See the reference link : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/

Answer (score 3):

Parameter descriptions for [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) from the documentation:

> `void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );`
>
> `destination`: Pointer to the destination array where the content is to be copied,
>   type-casted to a pointer of type void*.
>
> `source`: Pointer to the source of data to be copied, type-casted to a pointer of type const void*.
>
> `num`: Number of bytes to copy. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

`memcpy` simply takes `num` bytes starting from the address `source` and copies them to memory starting at address `destination`.

A pointer is a fixed length memory address, regardless of type. It does not matter whether the pointer is `char *` (points to character data), `int *` (points to integer data), or `void *` (points to data of unknown type), it still just points to memory.

Because `memcpy` copies an explicit number of bytes, the type of data being pointed to is irrelevant; it just need memory addresses to data.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what pointer it is really. It is a very plain process of having two memory addresses and engaging a copy.